# Something wrong with mysqli_fetch_array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I am trying to create a booking system in php and mysql with a datepicker.
When user selects a date a table with available period times should be displayed. If a time frame is available, the user should use the radio `input` and book that period of time.
If I'm using 
    `"ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1"`.
It gives me `8:22 exists`, and it's correct, but it not gives me the second statement, `8:30 exists`. Instead, for 8.30 it creates available time frame `8:30-8:38`.
If I'm using 
    `"ORDER BY start ASC"`. 
It multiplies the information based on how many records I have in database.
I can't see what is wrong ! 
Bellow are my code for mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start` enum('8:22-8:30','8:30-8:38','8:38-8:46','8:46-8:54','8:54-9:02','9:02-9:10','9:18-9:26','9:26-9:34','9:34-9:42','9:42-9:50','9:50-10:58','10:58-11:06','11:06-11:14','11:14-11:22','11:22-11:30','11:30-11:38','11:38-11:46','11:46-11:54','11:54-12:02','12:30-12:38','12:38-12:46','12:46-12:54','12:54-13:02','13:02-13:10','13:10-13:18','13:18-13:26','13:26-13:34','13:34-13:42','13:42-13:50','13:50-13:58','13:58-14:06','14:06-14:14','14:14-14:22','14:22-14:30','14:30-14:38','14:38-14:46','14:46-14:54','14:54-15:02','15:02-15:10','15:10-15:18','15:18-15:26','15:26-15:34') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `booked` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `start` (`start`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bookings`
--

INSERT INTO `bookings` (`id`, `date`, `start`, `booked`, `name`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES
(2, '2016-05-06', '8:30-8:38', '1', 'vcv', 'vxcv', 'xcvvc'),
(1, '2016-05-06', '8:22-8:30', '1', 'zxccxz', 'xczcc', 'zxczxc'),
(4, '2016-05-09', '9:02-9:10', '1', '', '', ''),
(3, '2016-05-09', '8:38-8:46', '1', '', '', '');
```

And the code for **index.php** is:

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

$post_at = "";
$post_at_to_date = "";

$queryCondition = "";
if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) {           
    $post_at = $_POST["search"]["post_at"];
    list($fid,$fim,$fiy) = explode("-",$post_at);

    $post_at_todate = date('Y-m-d');
    if(!empty($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) {
        $post_at_to_date = $_POST["search"]["post_at"];
        list($tid,$tim,$tiy) = explode("-",$_POST["search"]["post_at"]);
        $post_at_todate = "$tiy-$tim-$tid";
    }

    $queryCondition .= "WHERE date = '" . $post_at_todate . "' ";
}

$sql = "SELECT * from bookings " . $queryCondition . " ORDER BY start ASC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Recent Articles</title>      
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<style>
.table-content{border-top:#CCCCCC 4px solid; width:50%;}
.table-content th {padding:5px 20px; background: #F0F0F0;vertical-align:top;} 
.table-content td {padding:5px 20px; border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;vertical-align:top;} 
</style>
</head>

<body><input type="text" id="field_results" name="field_results" />  ...
<div class="demo-content">
    <h2 class="title_with_link">Recent Articles</h2>
  <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
 <p class="search_input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" name="search[post_at]" value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>" class="input-control" />          
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Search" >
</p>
<?php if(!empty($result))    { ?>
<table class="table-content">
      <thead>
    <tr>

      <th width="30%"><span>Day</span></th>
      <th width="50%"><span>Time period</span></th>           
      <th width="20%"><span>Book</span></th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<?php

    //while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if(preg_match('/8:22-8:30/',$row['start'])==TRUE){
            echo "8:22 exists";
        }else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>8:22-8:30</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '8:22-8:30' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/8:30-8:38/',$row['start'])==TRUE){
            echo "8:30 exists";
        }else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>8:30-8:38</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '8:30-8:38' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/8:38-8:46/',$row['start'])){
            echo "8:38 exists";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>8:38-8:46</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '8:38-8:46' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/8:46-8:54/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>8:46-8:54</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '8:46-8:54' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/8:54-9:02/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>8:54-9:02</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '8:54-9:02' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/9:02-9:10/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>9:02-9:10</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '9:02-9:10' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/9:18-9:26/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>9:18-9:26</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '9:18-9:26' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/9:26-9:34/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>9:26-9:34</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '9:26-9:34' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/9:34-9:42/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>9:34-9:42</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '9:34-9:42' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/9:42-9:50/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>9:42-9:50</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '9:42-9:50' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/9:50-10:58/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>9:50-10:58</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '9:50-10:58' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/10:58-11:06/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>10:58-11:06</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '10:58-11:06' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:06-11:14/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:06-11:14</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:06-11:14' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:14-11:22/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:14-11:22</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:14-11:22' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:22-11:30/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:22-11:30</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:22-11:30' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:30-11:38/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:30-11:38</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:30-11:38' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:38-11:46/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:38-11:46</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:38-11:46' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:46-11:54/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:46-11:54</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:46-11:54' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/11:54-12:02/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>11:54-12:02</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '11:54-12:02' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/12:30-12:38/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>12:30-12:38</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '12:30-12:38' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/12:38-12:46/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>12:38-12:46</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '12:38-12:46' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/12:46-12:54/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>12:46-12:54</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '12:46-12:54' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/12:54-13:02/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>12:54-13:02</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '12:54-13:02' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:02-13:10/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:02-13:10</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:02-13:10' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:10-13:18/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:10-13:18</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:10-13:18' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:18-13:26/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:18-13:26</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:18-13:26' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:26-13:34/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:26-13:34</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:26-13:34' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:34-13:42/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:34-13:42</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:34-13:42' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:42-13:50/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:42-13:50</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:42-13:50' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:50-13:58/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:50-13:58</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:50-13:58' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/13:58-14:06/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>13:58-14:06</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '13:58-14:06' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:06-14:14/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:06-14:14</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:06-14:14' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:14-14:22/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:14-14:22</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:14-14:22' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:22-14:30/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:22-14:30</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:22-14:30' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:30-14:38/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:30-14:38</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:30-14:38' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:38-14:46/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:38-14:46</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:38-14:46' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:46-14:54/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:46-14:54</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:46-14:54' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/14:54-15:02/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>14:54-15:02</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:54-15:02' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/15:02-15:10/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>15:02-15:10</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '14:54-15:02' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/15:10-15:18/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>15:10-15:18</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '15:10-15:18' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/15:18-15:26/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>15:18-15:26</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '15:18-15:26' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        if(preg_match('/15:26-15:34/',$row['start'])){
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$post_at</td>";
            echo "<td>15:26-15:34</td>";
            echo '<td><input class="text" type="radio" id="rez" name="rez" value="'. '15:26-15:34' .'"></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
 ?>
    <tr>


    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
<tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(":radio").on('click', function () {

    var fields = '';
    $(":radio").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            fields += $(this).val() + ' ';
        }
    });
    $('#field_results').val($.trim(fields))

});
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: The structure of the code looks right to me. Can you make a C9 out of it and share if possible?

Comment: `LIMIT 1` means you have only __1__ record in a result. What do you expect?

Comment: Nice spaghetti code !! You have crazy  redundancies.this code should be 20 lines.  Use switch and not if else, concat your html and echo only once. Where is ajax on date pick? Use ajax and append the div..

Answer (score 0):

From your "bookings" DB Table remove "UNIQUE KEY `start` (`start`)".

If you set "UNIQUE KEY" as any field then every time this field value must be unique.

Ex. if unique field value is blank for any one record, then other records should not be blank.

Comment: I've removed and the result it's still the same. What I want is to have only one time range booked for the entire day

Answer (score 0):

Just like what Mr. Price Hint said, setting *start* as *UNIQUE KEY* doesn't seem right.

However, I also see that you're probably facing this problem because of the way you setup the *start* in the DB.

I'd recommend switching from *start* as an *enum* : 
`'start' enum('8:22-8:30','8:30-8:38','8:38-8:46','8:46-8:54','8:54-9:02','9:02-9:10','9:18-9:26', etc...`
To making it as a reference to make things easier:
`'start' int(10)` and based on your needs you can make it `NOT NULL`
later when you make a *query* you can create a function that will convert the references into time periods by using a *switch case*
for example: 
`{case 1: echo 8:22-8:30}
 {case 2: echo 8:30-8:38}
 etc...`

This way you can sort them the way you want them, since they're numbers now, without worrying about them being converted, juggled, or miss ordered.

PS: LIMIT 1 means get only one result. That is the first raw that meets the condition only. You don't need a LIMIT at all.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: If I change the type from enum to int, how can I record the time frame:8:22-8:30 or 8:30-8:38 ?

Comment: by using a *switch case* statement:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

so instead of using all of those *if* statements you have you'll need to use a *while* condition statement http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp and to convert the numbers in the *start* field you'll use the *switch case* statement.

you've made your code very huge and unreadable by creating all of those *if* conditions to to mention that it will make the server incredibly busy!

Comment: How will you convert the numbers in the start field ?